# How to output divergence or gradient of a symbol in the form of partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector

As being new to divergence and gradient operators, I am trying to make them more readable, so could anyone tell me how can I output the divergence of u={{ux},{uy},{uz}} in the form of partial derivatives?
$$
\nabla\cdot u = \frac{\partial u_{x}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_{y}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_{z}}{\partial z}
$$

I've tried `u={{ux},{uy},{uz}}; Div[u,{x,y,z}]// Defer // TraditionalForm`, but the results was not as I expected.

Would much appreciate it if anyone could help!

Comment: Your `u` should be something like `u={ux, uy, uz}`, as you don’t need to try to force a column vector form with Mathematica. Also, you might consider that your parameters are all not dependent on anything, ergo they are constant in x, y, z; a possible solution to this would be to use something like `v={u[x,y,z],u[x,y,z],u[x,y,z]}`, but this might not be as mathematically proper as you would like it to be.

Comment: Does `u = {ux[x, y, z], uy[x, y, z], uz[x, y, z]}; Div[u, {x, y, z}]` meet your needs?